# Duplicate redis list

Tags: redis

Given I have a list stored in a key "A", how can I duplicate that list in a different key "B"?

I know that for non list values, I can "get", and then "set". But for lists when I try to get it, I see the WRONGTYPE operation error.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998281/how-to-copy-values-from-one-list-into-another-in-redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LRANGE` to get all elements of the first list, then use `LPUSH` or `RPUSH` to put these elements into the second list.

Answer (score 4):

Redis enables 5 different data structures, such as:

- Key values
- Strings
- Hashs
- Lists
- Sets

Each of the data structure has its own commands.

In order to get the current list you should use the **LRANGE** command.

The prefix L referes to the List data structure.

(Redis Set data structure has a related command to range by using **SETRANGE**)

If you read the [Redis LRANGE documentation](http://redis.io/commands/LRANGE) you will understand how to use it.

Here is the brief code you may use:

```
LRANGE mylist 0 -1
```

Where mylist is the list you get the values from.

> The offsets start and stop are zero-based indexes, with 0 being the
>   first element of the list (the head of the list), 1 being the next
>   element and so on.

-1 is used to describe the last element in the list.

Now you should use the [LPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) or [RPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/RPUSH) depends on the list side you wish to insert the old elements into the new list.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to duplicate a key's value, regardless the data structure, is to [`DUMP`](http://redis.io/commands/dump) it and then [`RESTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/restore) it into the new key. In most cases this approach is also the quickest.